# Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors of A and $A+\mu \mu^T$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider a $n\times n$ positive semidefinite matrix $A,$ and let $B$ and $C$
denote the matrix of eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors of $A$ such
that $AC=BC.$ Now, consider another matrix $A^{\ast }=A+\mu \mu ^{T}$ where $%
\mu $ ($n\times 1$ vector) denotes the row mean of $A.$ Also let $B^{\ast }$
and $C^{\ast }$ denote the eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors of $%
A^{\ast }$ such that $A^{\ast }C^{\ast }=B^{\ast }C^{\ast }.$ My question is
that are there any relationship between $B$ and $B^{\ast },$ $C$ and $%
C^{\ast }.$ Any reference on this? Thanks

Comment: If $\mu$ is an eigenvector of $A$, then there will be a very nice characterisation, if that interests you. In general, I suspect you won't get anything nice.

Comment: For search purposes (on this site and elsewhere) $A^*$ is an example of a (symmetric) rank-1 update of $A$. In particular there is the so-called [Bunch–Nielsen–Sorensen formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunch–Nielsen–Sorensen_formula) which expresses the new eigenvectors in terms of the old (but it also requires knowledge of the updated eigenvalues). In general such rank-one updates lead to rich problems which are often dealt with perturbatively.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Here, $\mu$ is simply the row means of $A$, so $\mu \mu^T$ is rank one.